# Ideal place for iAd Banner

Tags: ios, iad

I want to integrate iAd in my app. My app is tab based application. Most of my views have `TableView` in it. What can be the best place to display banner, should I display bottom of the `TableView` or top of the `TableView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom of the tableview is a good place to place the ads, as there are more chances the use will click on the ads when he/she wants to tap on the tabs. 
Check Other apps also. The app "FindHrr" I have developed has a similar design where we have placed the app below the tableview.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you setup banner for each view? Or you used a shared banner ?

Comment: We set the banner for each view.